# Is there a programmatic way to get the "Tracked By" relationship for github issues

Tags: github, github-api, github-cli, github-graphql

GitHub let's me create [tasks lists](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/about-task-lists) in the issue specification like so:

```
- [ ] #1
- [ ] https://github.com/desktop/desktop/pull/1
```

which will create a special relationship called "Tracked In" with the mentioned issue (see [docs here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/about-task-lists#navigating-tracked-issues)).
This is shown in the web-UI with a little icon "Tracked by `#<ISSUE-WITH-TASKLIST-NUMBER>`".

Is there any way via the API or CLI to find all issues that are "Tracked by" a specific issue?

I tried using the search [syntax for linked issues](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-for-linked-issues-and-pull-requests) but that seems to only apply to regular mentions of issues, not the specific "tracked by" relationship you get via task lists. That is, I cannot retrieve issues mentioned as part of a task list with the `linked:<ISSUE-NUMBER>` search syntax.

Is there some way of running a query that returns all issues tracked by a specific issue?

Comment: It looks like the API currently doesn't expose this, see [this comment](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/39106#discussioncomment-7261198) on fhe feedback discussion for tasklists.

Comment: Aha, thanks, I missed this. I think that is explains it then.